# How to execute a scheduled task with "schtasks" without opening a new command line window?

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a batch file that creates a scheduled task using `schtasks` like this:

```
schtasks /create /tn my_task_name 
                 /tr "...\my_path\my_task.bat"
                 /sc daily
                 /st 10:00:00 
                 /s \\my_computer_name 
                 /u my_username    
                 /p my_password
```

It works OK except the fact that when `my_task.bat` is executed - a new command line window is opened (and closed after execution).

I would like to avoid opening this new window (i.e. to run the task in quiet mode, in the background).

I thought to use

```
start /b ...\my_path\my_task.bat
```

but I don't know how, because since I have to call `start` from the batch file I need to precede it with `cmd /c`, which again causes the new window to open.

How could I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Windows Shell Scripting extensions to execute a batch file in invisible mode.

- Create a plain text file and name it `<scriptname>.vbs`
- Paste the following code in the .vbs file

  ```
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Batch Files\syncfiles.bat" & Chr(34), 0
    Set WshShell = Nothing
  ```
- Change the name and path of you batch file according to your need
- Save the .vbs file and schedule the same in schtasks

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. But I still wonder if it is impossible to do with a batch file...

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.  The proper solution is in the answer below from @mpod.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by specifying /RU option for schtasks. This option

> specifies the user account (user
>   context) under which the task runs.
>   For the system account, valid values
>   are "", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" or
>   "SYSTEM".

And thus, try this

```
schtasks /create /tn my_task_name 
                  ....
                 /st 10:00:00 
                 /ru "SYSTEM"
                 ....
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you don't have system privileges? I have script that works if I schedule it in the foreground, but when I add the /ru "SYSTEM" argument I get this error: `ERROR: Access is denied.`